# Best way to find the next/previous items in a javascript array of objects?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Let's say that you've got an array of page objects in Javascript:

```
pages = [{uid: 1, title: 'Home'},
{uid: 2, title: 'Products'},
{uid: 3, title: 'About'},
{uid: 4, title: 'Contact'}
]
```

Your goal is to create a method that, given the UID of the current page, returns the one that's next to it or the one that's previous to it (as defined by the order in the array).

*(updated) NOTE: You do not have access to the current page object, only its UID so you can't find its position using simply indexOf()*

```
nextPage = function (pages, currentPageUID){...}
previousPage = function(pages, currentPageUID){...}
```

In Javascript what would be the most elegant way to do this? It's a simple problem but the solutions I have thought of for it don't manage to reflect that simplicity and I'm sure there is one that would.

**BONUS**

Same question but for Coffeescript? (not sure how I'll reward it as a bonus but hopefully you'll feel good)

Comment: Have you considered changing the data structure? An map where the key is the UUID and the value is either a pointer to the row, or maybe the numeric index. This is the concept of a database index. If you make the value the numeric index, then you can simply add/subtract to get next/previous. If you have a handle to the current value, a doubly-linked-list data structure would give you immediate access to the previous and next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the most elegant way I can think of off the top of my head. I didn't flesh out the error checking though, so it just returns null if there isn't one.

```
nextPage = function (pages, currentPageUID){
  var i = pages.findIndex(function(p) { return p.uid === currentPageUID; });
  return (i > -1) ? (pages[i + 1] ? pages[i + 1] : null) : null; 
}

previousPage = function (pages, currentPageUID){
  var i = pages.findIndex(function(p) { return p.uid === currentPageUID; });
  return (i > -1) ? (pages[i -1] ? pages[i -1] : null) : null; 
}
```